# jargon for taking leftover budget funds in one calendar year and using them the next year

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There's a term for taking leftover budget funds in one calendar year and using them the next year, in the context of government budgeting.

I am having a brain freeze and can't remember it or find it on google. I know it's a reasonably short word (my guess is in the 5-9 letter range, 2-3 syllables) and it rhymes with a common word, possibly a food item. Don't ask me why I remember that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah: I found it. **encumber** (which rhymes with cucumber)

Here's an [example context from Wabash, Indiana](http://council.wabash.in.datapitstop.us/DATA/REPORTS/FLD00001/00002380.PDF):

> REQUEST TO ENCUMBER FUNDS INTO NEW YEAR
>
> This form is to be used for the encumbering of certain expenses from the current year's 
>   budget into the next budget year. The department must have remaining appropriations in 
>   their current budget line item in order to request encumbering. Please keep in mind that 
>   it is quite reasonable to pay for expenses incurred in December out of the new budget 
>   year's funds, since budgets are estimates only and the payment of expenses is deducted 
>   from the fund's cash balance regardless of when the payment is made.
>
> It is not necessary to request encumbering just to "use up" remaining amounts 
>   within a budgeted line item.
>
> Claims paid on December 19, 2011 will be taken from the current year's budget. Claims 
>   paid on January 9, 2012 (even with December 2011invoices) will be taken from the 
>   new budget year appropriations unless there is an approved request to encumber funds

or from [Kauai, Hawaii](http://www.kauaiwater.org/AgendaApr13.pdf):

> Chair Nishimura recommended that the conference funds be encumbered for next year if they are not used in the current budget this year.

other examples (look for "encumber" in these documents):

- http://www.amazon.com/forum/nonprofit%20management/Tx2IOCYO541NBPU
- http://nutpub.net/pdf_archive/2011_tritown_times/TTT-Jan6-2011.pdf
- http://www.hampton.lib.nh.us/library/trustees/minutes20121218.pdf
- http://www.ci.wilton.nh.us/Budget%20Committee/WebPage/2012/Minutes/Wilton%20Budget%20Committee%20Minutes%202011_12_01_Final.htm
- http://orlandfire.org/wp-content/uploads/About%20the%20District/Public%20Transparency/Elected%20and%20Administrative%20Officials/Board%20Agenda%20and%20Minutes/2011/12-20-11-Trustees-Regular-Agenda.pdf

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up? An *encumbrance* in financial trading contexts (and hence, included in accounts and feasibly *budgets*) is effectively an "outstanding commitment/debt". I've never heard of *encumber* used in the sense you've given. In fact, [encumbrance accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encumbrance) (including outstanding encumbrances in the accounts) is simply a means of making sure departments don't *overspend* (because if they see their "spoken-for" balance near the end of the year, they think they can spend it again, even though it's already committed).

Comment: I was on a town commission in New England and if our commission had funds left over at the end of the year, the only way to keep them in our commission's budget for next year was to have the Board of Selectmen encumber these funds. Otherwise they would go back into the town's General Fund.

Comment: @ Jason S: I can understand how *encumberances* affect apparently available funds, and obviously it's possible to imagine various flavours of meaning to a derived verb *encumber* there. But if your commission used it the way you say, I suggest this may have been a *highly* localised usage. In reality, you haven't taken "left over/spare" money at all - you've simply taken account of the fact that some money which has *already been "spent"* is still in the account, so it can't be "reclaimed" by the original fund providers.

Comment: OK, I can understand that... feel free to close as localized. I thought it was a general meaning. It may just be a New England thing.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe not. Here's an example usage for Washington County, Indiana: http://www.gbpnews.com/index.php?view=article&catid=37%3Awashingtoncountyedition&id=531%3Acommissioners-encumber-funds-for-horse-arena-improvements&format=pdf&option=com_content

Comment: Well, I suppose it's a matter of interpretation here. I can't square the definition as given in your question with, for example, *It is not necessary to request encumbering just to "use up" remaining amounts within a budgeted line item.* as cited in your answer.

Comment: When you have a hostile Board of Selectmen who keeps your commission's budget very low, and you have money left over in the budget, and you can't spend it this year but you can spend it next year on something, it is very necessary to request encumbering. :-)

Comment: -1 It is the **expenses** that are *encumbered* to the following  year -- not the funds. You could have interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: @Kris: I assume *expenses* are relevant if, for example, staff have already validly incurred them doing their jobs, but not yet claimed and been reimbursed. They're therefore *encumberances* on the organisation's balance sheet (assuming the outfit practices *encumbrance accounting*), so if that organisation relies on "external funding", the external outfit that provided those funds can't just take back the "encumberances" at the end of the year, because they're already "spent". It looks like a bit of a stretch to say you made that money safe from reclamation by "encumbering" it, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You could possibly encumber them *on* the following year; not encumber them *to* the following year. Still it is the expense entries that are encumbered not the funds -- the two are on opposite sides of the account book.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest "rollover" which is short, three syllables, but I can't think of a food item it rhymes with... not wait will "apple turnover" work? :-)

I don't think it is specific to governments, but it is a common word in finance meaning taking the excess or remainder and moving it into the next thing: think 401k rollover, or budget rollover.

Comment: Also, "carry-over". It doesn't make me think of cucumber, but I am thinking about a pizza now!